# How can I inject/hook into a running process to get information from it?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to learn about injecting/hooking running processes.

I have a game running, and in the game you can type /coord to get a print of what your current X, Y coordinates are. Basically I want to just have this done automatically through a program so I was looking into how I might do this with C# but I'm not exactly sure what I would google to start to learn how exactly I might do this, basically I just want a small GUI that will update the X/Y position automatically as I move around.

I'm not exactly sure where to start if anybody can just point me in the right direction that would be great.

If this is too off-topic / broad feel free to close it, sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really possible with c# only, unless the game is also written in c#, and you can somehow convince the game to load your module.

Otherwise, there will need to be atleast a native stub that starts up the .net runtime.

See this for an example of injecting native code in an application:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces

This native code can then bootstrap whatever intermediate language you will use.

On the other hand, reading the process memory can be done from any language that can use the Windows API, using `OpenProcess, ReadProcessMemory, CloseHandle`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm fairly new to the lower level of programming, is it possible to achieve it with Python instead do you know? Or do I have to kind of match what the program was written in?

Comment: If you want to inject python, there needs to be native code that bootstraps python. The same goes for every language that you can make up that does not run natively....

Comment: You do not need to match the language the program was written in, but you do need to write code that can be run directly from for example CreateRemoteThread.

Comment: Makes sense, do you know of any good tutorials or places I can start to learn about this in more depth?

Comment: How about the link i posted?